# Java LWJGL Slick TTF blur

Tags: java, lwjgl, blur, truetype, slick2d

I'm having a bit of trouble rendering textures and true type fonts at the same time.

The following screenshots portray my problem:

This shows the font rendering perfectly. This was before I was using textures.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tc9t.png

This shows the font after changing to textures. It goes all blurry.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/19bsh.png

I'm not sure how to fix this. I've tried enabling and disabling various things, but I can't figure it out.

Here's my code:

GL initialation:

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Sprite Rendering:

```
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        glPushMatrix();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.textureID);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2f(0, 0);

            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex2f(this.width, 0);

            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2f(this.width, this.height);

            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2f(0, this.height);
        }
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
```

Texture Loader:

```
    public static int loadTexture(BufferedImage image) {

    int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];
    image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0,
            image.getWidth());

    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth()
            * image.getHeight() * BYTES_PER_PIXEL); // 4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB

    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            int pixel = pixels[y * image.getWidth() + x];
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF)); // Red component
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF)); // Green component
            buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF)); // Blue component
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF)); // Alpha component.
                                                        // Only for RGBA
        }
    }

    buffer.flip(); // FOR THE LOVE OF GOD DO NOT FORGET THIS

    // You now have a ByteBuffer filled with the color data of each pixel.
    // Now just create a texture ID and bind it. Then you can load it using
    // whatever OpenGL method you want, for example:

    int textureID = glGenTextures(); // Generate texture ID
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); // Bind texture ID

    // Setup wrap mode
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // Setup texture scaling filtering
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // Send texel data to OpenGL
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    // Return the texture ID so we can bind it later again
    return textureID;
}
```

I'm willing to give any more information if necessary.
Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked 6 months ago at the time of this answer, but I just want other people to know in case they run into the same problem.

I had the same problem when I was experimenting with rendering images, too, and the fix for me was to unbind the texture after I finish rendering.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glPushMatrix();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.textureID);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
{
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(this.width, 0);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(this.width, this.height);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, this.height);
}
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```